# Is $\{(\emptyset, 1)\}$ empty?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a set in $\mathbb{R}^4$, we can write elements of this set as $(p, k)$ with $p \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $k \in \mathbb{R}$. If there is set that has the form of $\{(\emptyset, 1)\}$, is this an empty set or not?

Comment: It is not well-defined: you have to pick an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to make a couple. The standard way to do what you want is by picking the 0 vector.

Comment: Said another way, $\varnothing$ is not an element of $\Bbb R^3$. You have $\varnothing\subset\Bbb R^3$, but $\varnothing\notin\Bbb R^3$.